# How to disable the notification badge on Facebook on Sony Xperia?

Tags: notifications, facebook, sony-xperia

I have Sony Xperia. I hope to disable all attention grabbing behaviour on my phone, and after disabling notifications from most annoying apps, the only thing left is the notification badge (red number) on the Facebook app.

Browsing for "turn off notification badge android xperia facebook" only gives me hits regarding Samsung TouchWiz and iPhone, and I so far haven't been able to locate anything in the menu of the app either.

How can I turn off the display of unread events on the icon of the Facebook app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is no way to disable this in the default Xperia launcher. The easiest solution is to use a different launcher, like Apex, Nova, Epic launcher and such. The appearance of these launchers is different from the default one, but you may like it, and these launchers have many more customization options that you may also find appealing.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I thought the Xperia was pretty bloatware free, and that the launcher was the default Android one, but I guess I was wrong on that one :) Will check it out.